# screen display stops updating until program terminates

Tags: pygame, display

Attempting to display a series of screens, the first is displaed correctly
but on continuing,' (Not Responding)' is added to 1st screen caption
and there is no further change until the program terminates, when  the correct final screen caption number 3 appears.

```
# python 3.6  pygame 1.9.3
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
grey = (128,128,128,0)
Screen = pg.display.set_mode((1020,720))

for id in range(1,4):
    Screen.fill(grey)
    pg.display.set_caption('My new screen number '+str(id))
    # code to blit stuff onto the screen, not shown here
    pg.display.flip()
    input('examine screen and Enter to see the next one')
    continue
```

Comment: After the first screen is displayed,, the display hangs 'Not Responding'

Comment: until the program terminates.

Comment: Edit your questions rather than adding comments below them. I noticed you did this on your other questions as well and details might get lost in the comments if you keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue

Even if you don't want to handle events, you need to call [pygame.event.pump()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) to keep your operating system happy.

Also, `input` is a blocking operation, so you need it to run in a different thread so that your program can still pump the event queue every frame. At this point you should realise it'd be easier to handle events properly using pygame.

Here's an example, I've added a clock to limit the FPS so the CPU isn't pegged:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
grey = (128,128,128,0)
Screen = pg.display.set_mode((1020,720))
finished = False
id = ""
clock = pg.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
while not finished:
    for event in pg.event.get():            
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            finished = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            id = event.unicode
    Screen.fill(grey)
    pg.display.set_caption('My new screen number '+str(id))
    # code to blit stuff onto the screen, not shown here
    pg.display.flip()
    #input('examine screen and Enter to see the next one')
    clock.tick(60)
pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Eric for a comprehensive answer! Absolutely  Brilliant!